# Cannot modify association 'User#roles' because the source reflection class 'Role' is associated to 'Profile' via :has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models, a user, a profile and a role, where I'm trying to attach multiple **roles** to a **user** through **profile**.

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :roles, through: :profile
  has_many :interests, through: :profile
  has_many :industries, through: :profile
end

# profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :roles
  has_many :interests
  has_many :industries
end

# role.rb
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :profiles
  has_many :users, :through => :profiles
  has_many :users
end
```

I'm trying to use the following in **edit.html.erb** (simple_form_for)

```
<%= f.association :roles,
                   as: :check_boxes,
                   label_method: :name,
                   value_method: :id,
                   label: 'Roles' %>
```

With the following params

```
params.require(:user).permit([:email, :first_name, :last_name, :admin, :password, role_ids: [] ])
```

My edit/update method:

```
  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user.build_profile if @user.profile.nil?
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Gives me the following error message

> Cannot modify association 'User#roles' because the source reflection
>   class 'Role' is associated to 'Profile' via :has_many.

I've been looking at the problem for hours, but I can't seem to find the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with the way you have defined your relations.

`has_one` places the foreign key in the inverse side of the relation. So if you declare a relation with `has_one` in both ends ActiveRecord can't load the association. Instead you need to use `belongs_to` on the side with the foreign key:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
end

# profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When it comes to users and roles you are declaring has_many on both sides, but not telling ActiveRecord where to store the relation. In a bi-directional many to many relationship you need to use `has_many through:` with a join model or `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Usually when building a role based access system you would want to define the relationship so that a role `belongs_to` a single user instead of having a single `Admin` role for example with many users. This allows you to scope roles to resources and makes the logic of adding / removing roles much less complicated (you're adding (or removing) a role to/from a user, not adding or removing a user from a role.)

If you are authenticating / authorizing the User model you don't want to use `has_many :roles, through: :profiles` - the tri-parte join is going to be much slower and adds needless complexity and indirection.

If you really need to have a "profiles" table then use it for auxiliary info about the user and join it when needed instead.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, 
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
end

# Columns:
# - user_id [integer, index, foreign key]
# - resource_id [integer, index]
# - resource_type [string, index]
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true, 
                        dependent: :destroy
end

# Columns:
# - user_id [integer, index, foreign key]
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  # this is option but can be useful
  has_many :roles, through: :user
end
```

I would really recommend that you start by reading the official [rails guides article on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: In this case "Roles" can be read as "Occupation" (which I will rename it to) and I will use "Role" as it has been intended (using UserRole for that purpose now). The idea is that  "User" can be "Teacher", "Student" or "Admin" which will have many "Occupations", "Interests" and "Industries", which on their turn will be matched with "Lessons" and thus creating a relationship Teacher < Lesson > Student. Bare with me, as I've only been programming in Ruby for a few months.